# How to stop a program after an interval on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, pascal

In a **php** file I have this:

```
system("../my/my.sh aa.pas", $retval);
system("../my/aa");
```

where `aa` is an executable file.

How can I write a program that will stop execution if n seconds have passed?

I want to make a judging system.
It will check programs written in Pascal, C++ , etc. I need to stop the program if its execution time exceeds a specified limit.

Answer (score 0):

`$!` contains the pid (process id) of the last executed command. So can try this:

```
kill $!
```

Comment: but how can i do it when running time is more than 1 sec ?

Answer (score 0):

```
system('timeout n ../my/aa');
                ^
```

Where `n` is some integer value in seconds.

> If the command times out, then exit with status 124.  Otherwise, exit
>   with the status of COMMAND.  If no signal is specified, send the TERM
>   signal upon timeout.  The TERM signal kills any process that does not
>   block or catch that signal.  For other processes, it may be necessary
>   to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be caught.

Comment: thanks , but how i can know if my program finished or time was out ?

Comment: Run `timeout --help` to see on your machine what value is returned if a timeout occurs, then check that return value (by adding the optional parameter to `system()`). I've posted the exit statuses for my machine, perhaps they are the same on yours.

Comment: Not a problem! If my post answered your question, please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as accepted.

Comment: i'm new here , my reputation is less than 15

Comment: do you know how to put memory limit ? i mean RAM

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$PID = shell_exec("nohup  ../my/aa > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

to start subprocess, wait in you main process for limit time, then

```
exec("kill -KILL $PID")
```

Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), search kill